# Extracting Latitude and Longitude from Image Exif Data: Validation Process

Tags: android, flutter, geolocation, exif

I have developed a mobile application using Flutter, featuring a functionality that allows users to upload images. Upon image upload, I aim to read the latitude and longitude information corresponding to the location where the image was captured.i have used EXIF from which IM not able to read latitude and longitude

Please help me with a feasible approach

i tried getting the latitude and longitude of a image using EXIF . im getting many info except latitude and longitude

Comment: Exif validation? What is that? You would read location information like lat,lon from exif header.

Comment: yes i want to read the information such as lat, lon from exif header in my application
@blackapps

Comment: Please edit your post then

Comment: done -blackapps

Comment: plzz help me out with this

Comment: You are still talking about 'validation'. Please edit your post.

Comment: tqsm sir  i have changed hope its making sence now 
pllz help if possible

Comment: Look at the subject of your post..